# How to put a PHP line in a PHP code using PHP?

Tags: php, function, variables, echo

I have a very simple PHP code (just an example):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "My first text bla bla bla";
print "My second text bla bla bla";
?>
</body>
<html>
```

Now my question is:

Can I echo `print "My second text bla bla bla";` in the PHP code? I try it of course using echo but I don't want it to echo as a **text** but as a real PHP line.

For example I can put a variable content this line `print "My second text bla bla bla";` and when I want to change it I change the content and the previews PHP code will change work when I load the webpage.

I search for solution and some people said use `htmlspecialchars()` but I don't want to display the line as a text when I load the webpage, BUT to put this line `print "My second text bla bla bla";` really in the PHP code and when I load the webpage it should works as:

```
<?php
echo "My first text bla bla bla";
print "My second text bla bla bla"; // This line should placed here when I load the webpage
?>
```

Comment: It's very confusing what you are trying to achieve and what you are asking.

Comment: Please make it a little clear what you want

Comment: I know it's easy to just put the line in its place but my question is to know if it's possible to place a php line inside php code for example using HTML form ( input ).
This can help if you want to place a function with another or edit it ( without edit the full webpage or see the full PHP code. @CharlieFish

Comment: @NadineAh I still don't understand what you are asking or what you want to do. You can place a PHP line in PHP code.

Comment: @CharlieFish

Lets say I have a php code with ( echo "TEXT"; ) .. and I want to delete it or replace it with another line for example ( print "TEXT2"; ) .. and I want to replace it just with a simple HTML form  imput and submit.
This is all the question about :) it's possible to do it or not ? replace a php line with another using PHP

Comment: `echo $var;` and change `$var` as needed. At least that is what i think you are asking

Comment: Inside of PHP you can't change PHP code. If you are trying to change the output value @Dagon is correct you could just create a variable `$var` and echo that variable and change that variable as needed. But you can't change the actual PHP code within PHP.

Comment: @Dagon
this useless because it will become a text ( HTML element ) in the webpage and not a PHP line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant write a php statement within a php statement. As soon as you use echo or print, the code inside echo/print will be rendered as html. The best you could do is store it within a variable. then you can change the variable $var.

```
$var = "My second text bla bla bla";
```

echo $var and print $var are basically the same and if you have to change it, change echo to print in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this. The difficulty when printing this line of code is getting around the double quotes, which are used to delimit the string. You can use single quotes to do so:

```
$code = 'print "My second text bla bla bla";';
echo $code;
```

Or, if you wish, you can still use double quotes, and then escape the inner ones:

```
$code = "print \"My second text bla bla bla\";";
echo $code;
```

The advice you have been given regarding `htmlspecialchars()` is suitable for printing HTML literally to the browser. For example this will result in a bold string:

```
echo "<strong>Hello</strong>";
```

However this will result in the HTML being printed out:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<strong>Hello</strong>");
```

It does this by converting special characters to their HTML entity equivalents, so the browser sees this:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Hello&lt;/strong&gt;
```